# passing variable to chef recipes and synchronization

Tags: chef-infra

As i am new to chef so want help.The secenario is to pass variables to chef recipes so that we can upload that recipes in chef server and it wil synchronised with chef client automatically.
how to pass variables to chef recipes and how it will synchronised with chef client

Comment: Chef uses attributes for storing values that are used by recipes, more about them you can find here https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html. If you have some more narrower issue please update your question so we can help you.

Comment: we have used this docs.chef.io/attributes.html.....attribute means variable with values...here the issues is we have to pass variables without values and values wil be passed at runtime.

Comment: Actually Chef doesn't work on that way, values should be provided by recipes, roles or environments, before actual chef run. There is some edge cases when you need to read values from contents of files on node, but in it must be defined in front, so you can achieve all features of Chef like  automatization and idempotency.

Comment: the scenario is like that we have to pass variable through the script and we have upload that to server and it wil run according to client needs.

Answer (score -1):

Chef uses attributes for variables.  You can set default attributes right within the cookbook.  Here is an example of that

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/06/chef-cookbook-directory-structure/

I generally set my run list in my role, and then set overwrite attributes within my environment files.

example environment ruby file:

```
`name "example_environment"
description "example_environmentfile"
override_attributes({
    'cookbook1' => {
        'database_password' => "password1",
        'server_password' => "password2"
    }
})`
```

here's an example of what a ruby role would look like:

```
`name 'example_role'
description 'example role with run list'
run_list(
    'recipe[cookbook1@2.0.9]',
    'recipe[cookbook1::recipe1@2.0.9]',
    'recipe[cookbook2::recipe2]'
)`
```

in the first line of the run list you can see i'm not specifying a recipe, this will call the default recipe of cookbook1.  I'm also specifying the version 2.0.9 cookbook here.

in the second line of the run list, i'm specifying it to run recipe1.

line 3 of the run list specifies to run recipe2 from cookbook2 of the latest version.